# NSLookup in PowerShell always throws RemoteException error

Tags: powershell, nslookup

When I run `nslookup` from a PowerShell script, I always get an error (which is output to the console) despite the fact the lookup succeeds:

```
PS C:\Windows\system32> $MyOutput = nslookup -q=SOA superuser.com
8.8.4.4 nslookup : Non-authoritative answer: At line:1 char:13
+ $MyOutput = nslookup -q=SOA superuser.com 8.8.4.4
+             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (Non-authoritative answer::String) [], RemoteException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError
```

This seems to be caused by the fact the answer is non-authoritative. Doing a lookup against an authoritative DNS server doesn't return an error.

In my attempts to find a solution myself, I found this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32395892/2227908). It suggests using the [Resolve-DNSName](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj590781(v=wps.630).aspx) command. Unfortunately that requires Windows 8.1/Server 2012 R2 and some of the systems my script will run on are Windows 7-era.

#### How can I prevent this error from being displayed?

*Bonus points for explaining why PowerShell thinks an error has occurred!*

Comment: you can try using `[System.Net.Dns]::Resolve("superuser.com")` instead of `Resolve-DNSName` cmdlet. Regarding `nslookup`, interestingly it is not throwing an error in Posh 5, but directs the `Non-authoritative answer:` to the console (even though output is assinged to variable - just as in your example)

Comment: you should be able to prevent it, if you set `$ErrorActionPreference = "SilentlyContinue"` at the beginning of your script. Keep in mind that this will surpress any error in the script from being displayed

Comment: `$MyOutput = nslookup -q=SOA superuser.com 2>$null` should suffice as `nslookup` posts the `Non-authoritative answer:` message to stdERR. For proof, run `>NUL nslookup -q=SOA superuser.com` as well as `2>NUL nslookup -q=SOA superuser.com` from an open `cmd` window…

Comment: As the comments suggest, this varies per version of Powershell. If using v5, the `Non-authoritative answer:` line can be excluded via the `2>$null` redirect. If using a lesser version where an error is the output, you could modify the `$ErrorActionPreference`. Don't think `-ErrorAction` will be available here. There are other .NET alternatives, including `[System.Net.Dns]::GetHostAddresses("superuser.com")`.

Comment: There's also a PowerShell alternative man.... `Resolve-DNSName <domain.com>`—test it out when or if you ever get a chance and if it's applicable with your PS versions in your environment. [Resolve-DNSName](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/dnsclient/resolve-dnsname?view=winserver2012r2-ps)

Comment: @ITSnuggles Some of the systems I am doing this on are Windows 7 and the version of PS with that cmdlet don't run on that OS. :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Ignore the executable's error by redirecting to $null

**Your executable is sending output to the STDERR stream.**  You can suppress it by redirecting it to the automatic $null variable:

```
nslookup.exe example.com 2>$null
```

Notes:

- You must redirect to PowerShell's `$null` variable. PS won't let you do it the old school way (i.e. `2>nul`).
- Redirecting to `$null` [is faster](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5263780/2227908) than using `Out-Null`

---

### Explanation

NSLookup is sending a portion of its output to the [STDERR stream](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/110930/redirecting-error-messages-from-command-prompt-stderr-stdout). Whenever a Windows console application does this, PowerShell reports this as a *NativeCommandError* error.

In Command Prompt run `nslookup -q=SOA superuser.com 1>nul 2>con` to see what NSLookup is writing to STDERR:

> Non-authoritative answer:

This is *exactly* what PowerShell returns in the first line of its error message:

> nslookup : Non-authoritative answer:
>   At line:1 char:1
>   + nslookup -q=ns example.com

Apparently NSLookup returns an error when its answer includes records from a non-authoritative name server. However in your case that doesn't seem to be a problem so you can ignore the error as described above.